# Xero .. get link to Invoice PDF

Tags: xero-api

How do I get a link to a PDF of an Invoice. I want to send the link to clients so they can see the invoice.  I don't want to download the pdf and send that.  Just a link. I found the documentation confusing.
An example would be great.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.